# What does name: ' XXX |||| XXXs', mean in i18n?

Tags: typescript, react-admin, react-i18next

This code is from recat-admin [demo](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/i18n/en.ts) i18n translation,

```
     invoices: {
        name: 'Invoice |||| Invoices',
        fields: {
            date: 'Invoice date',
            customer_id: 'Customer',
            command_id: 'Order',
            date_gte: 'Passed Since',
            date_lte: 'Passed Before',
            total_gte: 'Min amount',
            address: 'Address',
        },
    },
```

Could you explain me what does this row mean?

```
name: 'Invoice |||| Invoices'
```

I have never come across such a code with ||||

Thank you:)

Comment: react-admin i18n uses polyglot, this is template statement of  polyglotjs.

[Translation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#introducing-the-i18nprovider)

[polyglot](https://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-admin uses [Polyglot](https://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/#pluralization) as its default i18n provider. This is how you define singular and plural forms of a message:

`name: 'Singular |||| Plural'`

In some languages, you might need more than two variations:

`name: 'WhenZero |||| WhenOne |||| WhenMoreThanOne'`

In react-admin, you can call the `useTranslate` hook to get a `translate` function. This function accepts 2 arguments:

- the translation key
- an object of variables to interpolate in the translated message.

If you read polyglot documentation, you'll see there is a special variable you can pass in the second argument, called `smart_count`. This variable is used by polyglot to return the correct pluralized form of your message.

react-admin use this feature to get the correct title. In the case of the resource name, we display the pluralized version for the list page and the menu items, and the singular one for create, edit and show.

Comment: Thank you! ok I understand that. but how does it know when to use in what?

Comment: I added more details